# Java File Scanning multiple lines and variable types

Tags: java

Trying to scan a file that has numerous lines, multiple types of variables and multiple segments (maybe not the best word to describe it?)

Basically this is my file input (placeholders to better explain):

```
String1
int1
double1

String2
int2
double2

String3
int3
double3
```

I'm wondering what the best way to get this data read so that it can be used in basic equations.

I've looked into using Scanner but it seems due to the multiple lines I may be better using BufferedReader and then converting each line from a string to say an integer or a double if needed (or am I over complicating this?).

I have some previous experience with C++ but nothing further than basic for loops and arrays, so please try to keep this as clear and beginner proof as possible.

Comment: Is `String#` only one word, or can it contain more than one words (separated by whitespace)?

Comment: @Pshemo just one word :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file goes string,int,double,blank line,string,int,double,...
We can easily use a while loop for this.
Make 3 Arraylists that hold the corresponding strings, ints, and doubles.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file path here"));

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        strings.add(file.nextLine());
        ints.add(Integer.parseInt(file.nextLine()));
        doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(file.nextLine()));
        if(file.hasNextLine())
            file.nextLine();
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: First thank you for the response! Once this data is in the array list how would I go about using each variable?

Comment: Managed to get this all finished thanks to your comment and code. Thank you!